# How to avoid that Drupal encodes my url

Tags: uri

I use hook_url_outbound_alter to change my url to /q=anything, but the url in browser is shown as /q%3Danything. How can I avoid that Drupal encodes the url?

Other choice would be to send q=anything as query, but then hook_url_outbound_alter includes the "?" character, and I can't include it.

```
if (preg_match('|^search/node/(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
  $path = 'q=' . $matches[1];
}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't need to add the "q=" drupal will deal with that side of things, especially when you turn on clean urls.

Comment: I use clean urls, but I need that search url be "/q=anything". As I said, with $options['query'] Drupal set url to "/?q=anything", but introduce "?".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `?q=anything` to the path you should add your query as an option to the `$options` array.

```
if (preg_match('|^search/node/(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
  $options['query'] => array('q' => 'anything');
}
```

Comment: But if I add ?q=anything with $options, how do I remove the character "?" from the path?

Comment: /q=test is not a valid URL. The = character is something that tells the value of a query (?).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a path like q=anything without encoding the equal sign; that is done to avoid problems with a path like q=anything?parameter=value. Your alternatives are just two:

- Get the question mark before the q doing as Pontus Nilsson said
- Avoid using q=anything, and use q/anything

The latter is what Drupal normally does. In fact, the path for a node is node/node-id, not node=node-id; the path for a user profile is user/user-id, not user=user-id.

Keep in mind that a clean path like node/1 is translated to index.php?q=node/1 in the .htaccess file. In your case, q=anything would be translated to index.php?q=q=anything. That is the reason why the second equal sign needs to be encoded.

Comment: This question is due to that SEO people need to change the usual path of search "search/node/anything" to "q=anything", and it is getting harder than I thought.